# Unity3D standard asset script not functioning properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to complete a project using unity3D standard assets. But while importing the assets the scripts were creating an error - "No MonoBehavior scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name." and another error - "Assets\Standard Assets\Characters\RollerBall\Scripts\BallUserControl.cs(3,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CrossPlatformInput' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityStandardAssets' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". As I am new to unity and although I have prior knowledge but not in C# I am not understanding the errors. I have also given a script below for finding the problem.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Ball
{
    public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private float m_MovePower = 5; // The force added to the ball to move it.
        [SerializeField] private bool m_UseTorque = true; // Whether or not to use torque to move the ball.
        [SerializeField] private float m_MaxAngularVelocity = 25; // The maximum velocity the ball can rotate at.
        [SerializeField] private float m_JumpPower = 2; // The force added to the ball when it jumps.

        private const float k_GroundRayLength = 1f; // The length of the ray to check if the ball is grounded.
        private Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;


        private void Start()
        {
            m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            // Set the maximum angular velocity.
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().maxAngularVelocity = m_MaxAngularVelocity;
        }


        public void Move(Vector3 moveDirection, bool jump)
        {
            // If using torque to rotate the ball...
            if (m_UseTorque)
            {
                // ... add torque around the axis defined by the move direction.
                m_Rigidbody.AddTorque(new Vector3(moveDirection.z, 0, -moveDirection.x)*m_MovePower);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise add force in the move direction.
                m_Rigidbody.AddForce(moveDirection*m_MovePower);
            }

            // If on the ground and jump is pressed...
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, k_GroundRayLength) && jump)
            {
                // ... add force in upwards.
                m_Rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up*m_JumpPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you install all the items in the standard assets package or just a few bits?

Comment: First I tried importing all the items and again just a few bits but nothing worked @BugFinder

Comment: well i imported all the standard assets, fixd an error about guitext and my rollball works.. so.. the standard assets work its something you arent doing or are doing that is blocking it.. There isnt enough detail.. as I opened a blank project imported the asset fixed simpleactivatormenu as it was complaining.. its all fine.. so. which version of unity are you using